# No contiene ninguna definición de extensión o instancia pública para "GetEnumerator"

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

La verdad es la primera vez que me pasa, no sé por qué me salta éste error cuando quiero hacer una tabla en la vista. Estoy trabajando en MVC ASP.NET

Vista:

```
@model PrototipoAdminTemplate.Models.ParametrosCanalesValores

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AltaParametros";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<title>Parámetros</title>
<br />

@using (Html.BeginForm("AltaParametros", "Empresas", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <h1>Parámetros</h1>

    <body>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr class="header">
                    <th><h3>Parámetro</h3></th>
                    <th><h3>Canal</h3></th>
                    <th><h3>Valor</h3></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                @foreach(var p in Model) 
                {                 
                    <tr>
                        <td>@p.ValorDefault</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>

        </table>
    </body>
```

Modelo:

```
 public partial class ParametrosCanalesValores
    {
        public int ParametroId { get; set; }
        public short CanalId { get; set; }
        public string ValorDefault { get; set; }
    
        public virtual Canales Canales { get; set; }
        public virtual Parametros Parametros { get; set; }
    }
```

El problema aparece en el "Model" del foreach en el tbody:

```
<tbody>
               @foreach(var p in Model)
               {                 
                   <tr>
                       <td>@p.ValorDefault</td>
                   </tr>
               }
           </tbody>
```

En el controlador todavía no lo estoy usando, no sé si debería usarlo para evitar el error.
Cualquier ayuda se los agradecería.

Comment: model.algo????????

Comment: No entiendo que quieres hacer. La clase `ParametrosCanalesValores` no implementa `IEnumerable` por lo que no puedes usarlo en un `foreach`.

Comment: Como puedo implementar ek IEnumerable para que me funcione el Model?

Answer (score 0):

El tipo de tu modelo no es de tipo `IEnumerable` por lo que no es posible utilizarlo en un `foreach`.

Cambia:

```
@model PrototipoAdminTemplate.Models.ParametrosCanalesValores
```

A:

```
@model IEnumerable<PrototipoAdminTemplate.Models.ParametrosCanalesValores>
```